# "Unreadable" CDs in MacOS Sonoma

Tags: mount, compact-disc, macos-sonoma

I have some commercial CDs, such as the CD that came with my Nikon Camera. My Mac claims they are unreadble by this computer (Macbook Air running Sonoma with a Origbelie USB DVD (R/RW) drive.) Yet I can mount them using the cd9660.util at a directory I created in /Volumes (namely /Volumes/tempCD.)
Diskutil results in:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:        CD_partition_scheme                        *846.4 MB   disk2
   1:     Apple_partition_scheme                         298.6 MB   disk2s1
   2:        Apple_partition_map                         1.0 KB     disk2s1s1
                    (free space)                         193.3 MB   -
   3:                  Apple_HFS                         104.9 MB   disk2s1s2
```

after cd'ing into /System/Library/Filesystems/cd9660.fs/Contents/Resources and running sudo ./cd9660.util -M disk2s1 /Volumes/tempCD I can see the files in tempCD:

```
 AUTORUN.INF        Items           QuickTime 7
Camera Control Pro  NikonDx.inf     Welcome.exe
DirectX 9       NikonDx.sys
Drivers         PictureProject
```

The only thing I can guess is the reason the CDs aren't readable is because they don't have anything in the "NAME" column on the Apple_HFS line. Other readable CDs do have a NAME.
The question, which I didn't make entirely clear, is why can't MacOS mount these disks in the normal way?
Upon further investigation I have found that some CDs which show the same types of partitions in diskutil list cannot be mounted with commands cd9660.util command. I've also tried the mount command which also fails.